# Save data from an LCD KeyPad Shield to an sd card

Tags: arduino-ide, sd-card

I'm developing a project that requires save data from a sensor that is connected in a LCD keypad shield, the information should be save in a file into SD card.

My code

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <SD.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);

int buttons;
File myFile;
//name of the file
char nombrefichero[12];
int i = 1;
int exist = LOW ;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
//check the sd card adapter
  Serial.print("Iniciando SD ...");
  if (!SD.begin(53)) {
    Serial.println("No se pudo inicializar");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("inicializacion exitosa");
}

void loop() {
// use the buttons of the lcd keypand shield in analog 0
buttons = analogRead(0);

//button right
if(buttons < 50){
  count ++;
  nuevo();
}

//button select
if(buttons < 790){
  capturar();
}

}

void capturar(){
  myFile = SD.open(nombrefichero, FILE_WRITE);//abrimos  el archivo

  if (myFile) { 
        Serial.print("Escribiendo SD: ");
        int sensor1 = analogRead(0);
        int sensor2 = analogRead(1);
        int sensor3 = analogRead(2);
        myFile.print(millis());
        myFile.print(",");
        myFile.print(sensor1);
        myFile.print(",");
        myFile.print(sensor2);
        myFile.print(",");
        myFile.println(sensor3);

        myFile.close(); //cerramos el archivo

        Serial.print("Tiempo(ms)=");
        Serial.print(millis());
        Serial.print(",sensor1=");
        Serial.print(sensor1);
        Serial.print(",sensor2=");
        Serial.print(sensor2);
        Serial.print(",sensor3=");
        Serial.println(sensor3);       


  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("Error al abrir el archivo");
  }
  delay(1000);
}

void nuevo(){

while (exist == LOW)
  {
    sprintf(nombrefichero, "M%d.txt",i); //generate autoincrement number of 
file

    if(SD.exists(nombrefichero))
    {
       i = i+1;
      myFile = SD.open(nombrefichero, FILE_WRITE);
      if (myFile) {
        Serial.println("Archivo nuevo, Escribiendo encabezado(fila 1)");
        myFile.println("Tiempo(ms),Sensor1,Sensor2,Sensor3");

        myFile.close();

      } else {
        exist = HIGH;
        Serial.println("Error creando el archivo");
      }
  }

  }
}
```

I need capture the information of the sensor when I pressed the select button and when the right button is press create a new file in this method, in this line if(SD.exists(nombrefichero)) if I put the ! before SD.exist the files are created infinite but if I leave it as is without the ! the button does nothing

```cpp
void nuevo(){

while (exist == LOW)
  {
    sprintf(nombrefichero, "M%d.txt",i); 
    if(SD.exists(nombrefichero))
    {
       i = i+1;
      myFile = SD.open(nombrefichero, FILE_WRITE);
      if (myFile) {
        Serial.println("Archivo nuevo, Escribiendo encabezado(fila 1)");
        myFile.println("Tiempo(ms),Sensor1,Sensor2,Sensor3");

        myFile.close();

      } else {
        exist = HIGH;
        Serial.println("Error creando el archivo");
      }
  }

  }
}
```

I'm use arduino mega 2560 and SD card Adapter

Comment: [Don't cross post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) You already [asked this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47425316).